# Fixtures not loaded using minitest to test services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I have added an /app/services directory in my Rails app where I put some business logic that is not related to a specific DB table and/or that may call some external APIs.

I also added this to my Rakefile :

```
namespace :test do
  desc "Test tests/services/* code"
  Rails::TestTask.new(:services) do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/services/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end

Rake::Task['test:run'].enhance ["test:services"]
```

As you can see, my tests are located inside "/test/services".

Now all tests can be performed using "spring rake test", except that fixtures aren't loaded at all for services. Worst, if I try adding "fixtures :all" at the top of a service test Class, I get a "undefined method `fixture' for #

Do you have an idea about how I can load fixtures for tests located in a non regular directory ?

Comment: Are your tests inheriting from ActiveSupport::TestCase? Tests that inherit directly from Minitest::Test won't be run in the database transaction needed for fixtures.

Comment: Actually, I use MiniTest and I just start my tests the exact same way I would do for a Model (eg: describe MyService do ...). How do I make them inherit from ActiveSupport::TestCase ? They're not like a regular Class, do they ?

Comment: Replace the outer "describe" with "class MyServiceTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase".

Comment: You can replace the `describe` with a class declaration, like @ChrisKottom says. Or, if you are using minitest-rails 2.1+ you can say `describe MyService, :model do` which will make the test inherit from the correct class. Older versions of Minitest and minitest-rails don't support that however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, thanks Chris Kottom you've got the answer ! The trick was just to use this :

```
require 'test_helper'

class VatTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    # My test code

end
```

Instead of this :

```
require 'test_helper'

describe Vat do

    # My test code

end
```

Although the latest way for writing the test works, this does not load fixtures.